# Gives Error on SPARK REPL (reference to A is ambiguous ) and Works fine in Intellij and Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, class, apache-spark, read-eval-print-loop, companion-object

I have a sample code :

```
    class A(str: String) {
  println(s"InsideCase:::$str")
}

object A {
  def apply(str: String) = {
    println("foobar::")
    new A(str)
  }
}

object b extends App {
  A("kool")
}
```

This code works fine in Intellij. And gives me output:

```
foobar::
InsideCAse:::kool
```

But When Try to do this on REPL :

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class A(str: String) {
  println(s"InsideCAse:::$str")
}

object A {
  def apply(str: String) = {
    println("foobar::")
    new A(str)
  }
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A
defined object A

scala> A("kool")
```

It gives me the following error :

```
<console>:27: error: reference to A is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import $line31$read.A
and import INSTANCE.A
       A("kool")
```

What am I missing here ? If you can please explain in detail that would be helpful.

Comment: It's working fine for me.

Comment: It works on Scala REPL then Why does it not work on SPARK REPL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Spark REPL limitation. You can either do it an old school way with an object wrapper:

```
object awrapper {

  class A(str: String) {
    println(s"InsideCAse:::$str")
  }

  object A {
    def apply(str: String) = {
      println("foobar::")
      new A(str)
    }
  }
}

import awrapper._
```

or define a package with `paste -raw` (Scala 2.11+):

```
scala> :paste -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package apacakage

class A(str: String) {
  println(s"InsideCAse:::$str")
}

object A {
  def apply(str: String) = {
    println("foobar::")
    new A(str)
  }
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> import apacakage._
import apacakage._

scala> A("kool")
foobar::
InsideCAse:::kool
res1: apacakage.A = apacakage.A@6e818345
```